# Calling one fragment from other fragment Error?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am calling one fragment called MilkingFragment from other fragment called CommonHome I used this code

```
            Fragment fragment=new MilkingFragment("me");

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER,  1);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

            getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
```

But its showing error it's crashing. How can I solve this.

Error is

```
 12-13 18:54:52.931: E/AndroidRuntime(6692): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 12-13 18:54:52.931: E/AndroidRuntime(6692): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No 
    view found for id 0x7f0a0001 (com.tcs.ignite.pashupalan:id/content_frame) for  
 fragment  MilkingFragment{41aba808 #0 id=0x7f0a0001}
12-13 18:54:52.931: E/AndroidRuntime(6692):     at    
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:919)
12-13 18:54:52.931: E/AndroidRuntime(6692):     at 
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)

12-13 18:54:52.931: E/AndroidRuntime(6692):     at   
android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
 12-13 18:54:52.931: E/AndroidRuntime(6692):    at     

android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
12-13 18:54:52.931: E/AndroidRuntime(6692):     at 
 android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
 12-13 18:54:52.931: E/AndroidRuntime(6692):    at 
 android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to add your fragment to a container that does not exist.

i.e your layout does not have a view called `content_frame`